# Subset of a tensor based on contiguous equality of another tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say, i have two tensors in tensorflow as follows:

```
superset = [1,6,7,4,5,6,3,4,8,9,3,2]. 

subset = [6,3,4,8].
```

How do i get a boolean tensor indicating the span of the subset in superset .i.e
i need a tensor as follows:

```
intersect = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0].
```

in tensorflow?

This is what i have now, is there a better way?

```
def getsubset(superset, subset):
    result = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(superset):
        print(i)
        if i+len(subset) >= len(superset):
            result.append(0.0)
            i += 1
            continue
        if all(tf.equal(superset[i:i+len(subset)], subset)):
            for k in range(len(subset)):
                result.append(1.0)
                i += 1
        else:
            result.append(0.0)
            i +=1
    return result
```